# How to make the app run again in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a game that I think of a number, and the computer has to guess it. This is what I have:

```
import random
low = 1
high = 100
def guess_attempt():
    guess_attempt = random.randint(low, high)
    return guess_attempt   
def game():
    print("Lets play a game, think in number and I will try to guess it")
    print("Is the number ", guess_attempt()," that you thought?")
    response = eval(input("Type L if its to low, H if its to high or C if its correct "))
    if response == "L":
        low = guess_attempt
    if response == "H":
        high = guess_attempt
    if response == "C":
        high = 100
        low = 1
    while(response != 'C'):
        print("Okay, lets try again")
    print("I knew I could guess it")

game()
```

I dont know how to make it start again when i let the computer know it had a wrong number

Answer (score 0):

A standard way to do this would be to put the part of the code that asks the question and receives the answer in an infinite loop which the program only breaks out of if you supply a correct answer (or a quit command).

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few changes. The following code works,

```
import random

def guess_attempt(low, high):
    return random.randint(low, high)

def game():
    low = 1
    high = 100
    print("Lets play a game, think in number between 1 and 100. I will try to guess it")
    g = guess_attempt(low, high)
    print("Is the number {} that you thought?".format(g))
    response = input("Type L if its to low, H if its to high or C if its correct ").strip()
    while(response != 'C'):
        if response == 'L':
            low = g
        elif response == 'H':
            high = g
        g = guess_attempt(low, high)
        print("Is the number ",g," that you thought?")
        response = input("Type L if its to low, H if its to high or C if its correct ").strip()
    print("I knew I could guess it is {}".format(g))

game()
```